# AngularJS Update value in scope object inside foreach

Tags: angularjs, scope

I need to recalculate some values inside scope object on form submit.

So i've got:

```
 $scope.submit = function() {
       if ($scope.searchPlace) {
       var address = $scope.searchPlace + ', ' $scope.land;
       geocodeAddress(address, function(latLng){
          angular.forEach($scope.places,function(value,key){
            var distance = getDistance(value.latitude,value.longitude,latLng.lat(),latLng.lng())
            value.distance = distance;
           });
         });
     }
 };
```

$scope.places is something like [{'name':'place_a', 'distance': 0}, {'name':'place_b', 'distance': 0}]

But I can not see any changes to scope object in frontend. What am I missing?

Here are both functions used above

```
var getDistance = function(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
            var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
            var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
            var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
            var a =
            Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2)
            ;
            var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
            var d = R * c; // Distance in km
            return d;
        }


var geocodeAddress = function(address, callback) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    callback(results[0].geometry.location);
                } else {
                    console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: what is `geocodeAddress()`??

Comment: a function that makes calculations. It works ok and returns some values. distance is a numerical value. If i log results to console, everything is ok. The only problem - i don't see scope updates

Comment: Post its code. It matters.

Comment: If the getdistance function has any $http calls, then the value will not updated if you don't return a promise.

Comment: I've added both functions to question

Comment: What is not showing up on the front end, which value are you looking at here to show  changes? It doesn't look like your changing any $scope variables, just looping through them.

Comment: I want to change 'distance' values (0 by default) i've tried it in different ways, e g $scope.places[key]['distance'] = distance...

Answer (score 0):

If `getDistance` function returns a promise, you should use it like this :

```
getDistance(value.latitude,value.longitude,latLng.lat(),latLng.lng()).then(function(response){
    var distance = response.data;
    value.distance = distance;
});
```

Comment: There is no promise... do I have to add it? it's simple calculation

Comment: @Sobakinet it's better to add getDistance's code to your question

Comment: it's in question